# How to remove all spaces, newlines, tabs from byte array?

Tags: json, go

I am writing a test where I want to compare the result of `json.Marshal` with a static json string:

```
var json = []byte(`{
    "foo": "bar"
}`)
```

As the result of `json.Marshal` does not have any `\n`, `\t` and spaces I thought I could easily do:

```
bytes.Trim(json, " \n\t")
```

to remove all of these characters.
However unfortunately this does not work. I could write a custom trim function and use `bytes.TrimFunc` but this seems to complicated to me.

**What else could I do to have a json string "compressed" with as less code as possible?**

Best,
Bo

Comment: You need a replace function, not a trimming function. But what if you have spaces inside keys and values? how can you tell if you're inside a key/value or not? you can't without writing a JSON parser :) so you're stuck in a loop here, unless you are 100% sure all spaces in the json are padding and not in keys/values. otherwise, just use `strings.Replace` :)

Comment: Since it's a byte array and not a string you can use `bytes.Replace` instead.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Using any trimming or replace function will not work in case there are spaces inside JSON strings. You would break the data, for example if you have something like `{"foo": "bar baz"}`.

Just use [json.Compact](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Compact).

This does exactly what you need, except that it outputs to a `bytes.Buffer`.

```
var json_bytes = []byte(`{
    "foo": "bar"
}`)
buffer := new(bytes.Buffer)
if err := json.Compact(buffer, json_bytes); err != nil {
     fmt.Println(err)
}
```

See http://play.golang.org/p/0JMCyLk4Sg for a live example.

Comment: Thanks for the simple solution. Exact the thing I was looking for.

Comment: Nice, never realized json.Compact even existed.

Comment: To use the buffer as a byte array, simply do `buffer.Bytes()`